# Connecting to cluster with cqlsh returns "Unable to connect to any servers"

Tags: cassandra, hive

I am trying to deploy The Hive 4 on a VMware Workstation 17 player VM to test Splunk integration with The Hive.
I am following the guide at this [link](https://docs.thehive-project.org/thehive/installation-and-configuration/installation/step-by-step-guide/), but I encountered an error at one of the stages, namely when launching cassandra using the `cqlsh localhost 9042` command:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I tried to solve the problem based on the information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121904/cassandra-cqlsh-connection-refused) site, but it didn't help me.

OS Version - Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

I'm new in this field, I can provide any information you need

[image: cqlsh]

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far? It's important to know, so that people don't suggest things you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

This command does not "launch" Cassandra:

```
cqlsh localhost 9042
```

cqlsh is a client that connects to a Cassandra cluster so you can run CQL commands/statements.

The "Connection refused" error is a low-level TCP error that tells you there is no process/daemon listening for connections on port `9042`. Another way of putting it is that Cassandra is not running on the VM so cqlsh can't connect to it.

The installation instruction in [the link you posted](https://docs.thehive-project.org/thehive/installation-and-configuration/installation/step-by-step-guide/) is out-of-date. See the [Getting Started Guide](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/index.html) on the Apache Cassandra website for detailed instructions for installing Cassandra. Cheers!